# CakePHP 3.7 - Intervention ImageUpload error "Unable read image from path"

Tags: php, cakephp, imagemagick, image-upload, intervention

I suddenly have and image upload error in my cakephp application. Everything was working normaly but then suddenly this error. Check this screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/ssazr5

I make and updates once in a while but I havenot made any changes regarding image upload.

I really have no clue why is this happening?
Maby something cache related? 
That is where I have made some updates - deleted some files and compiled new translation files.

Here is my controller

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $product = $this->Products->get($id, [
            'contain' => [
                'Images',
                'Categories',
                'ChildProducts',
                'AttributeValues',
                'AttributeValues.Attributes'
            ]
        ]);

        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            if (!$this->request->getData('images')) {
                $this->request->data['images'] = [];
            }

            $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData(), [
                'associated' => ['Images', 'AttributeValues']
            ]);

            if ($this->Products->save($product, ['associated' => ['Images', 'AttributeValues'] ])) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));
                return $this->Redirecter->goBack();
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

        $this->AttributesHandler->setAttributes(
            !empty($product->category_id) ? $product->category_id : null,
            $product->id
        );

        $categories = $this->Products->Categories->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('productType', 'product', 'categories'/*, 'attributes'*/));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
    }
```

And here is Images upload method

```
 public function upload()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');

        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $image = $this->Images->newEntity($this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Images->save($image)) {
                $response = [
                    'id' => $image->id,
                    'url_sm' => '/upload/images/' . $image->id . '/sm_' . $image->image,
                    'url_md' => '/upload/images/' . $image->id . '/md_' . $image->image,
                    'url_lg' => '/upload/images/' . $image->id . '/lg_' . $image->image,
                    'status' => 'success'
                ];
                echo json_encode($response);
                return;
            }
        }

        echo json_encode([
            'status' => 'error'
        ]);
    }
```

And here is the model initialize

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('images');
        $this->displayField('filename');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('ImageUpload.ImageUpload', [
            'image' => [
                ['width' => 1500, 'height' => 850, 'quality' => 90, 'mode' => 'resize'],
                ['prefix' => 'md', 'width' => 320, 'height' => 180, 'quality' => 85, 'mode' => 'resize'],
                ['prefix' => 'sm', 'width' => 600, 'height' => 340, 'quality' => 80, 'mode' => 'fit']
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Nginx error.log

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.219.8.56, server: example.com, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

cakephp error.log

```
Caused by: [ImagickException] no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504
```

```
/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Imagick/Decoder.php(22): Imagick->readimage('/tmp/phpkBXa15')
#1 vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php(338): Intervention\Image\Imagick\Decoder->initFromPath('/tmp/phpkBXa15')
#2 vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDriver.php(64): Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder->init('/tmp/phpkBXa15')
#3 vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManager.php(52): Intervention\Image\AbstractDriver->init('/tmp/phpkBXa15')
#4 plugins/ImageUpload/src/Model/Behavior/ImageUploadBehavior.php(115): Intervention\Image\ImageManager->make('/tmp/phpkBXa15')
#5 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(353): ImageUpload\Model\Behavior\ImageUploadBehavior->beforeSave(Object(Cake\Event\Event), Object(App\Model\Entity\Product), Object(ArrayObject))
#6 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(330): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#7 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php(114): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#8 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1987): Cake\ORM\Table->dispatchEvent('Model.beforeSav...', Array)
#9 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1921): Cake\ORM\Table->_processSave(Object(App\Model\Entity\Product), Object(ArrayObject))
#10 endor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1634): Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM\{closure}()
#11 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(738): Cake\ORM\Table->Cake\ORM\{closure}(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
#12 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1635): Cake\Database\Connection->transactional(Object(Closure))
#13vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php(1922): Cake\ORM\Table->_executeTransaction(Object(Closure), true)
#14 src/Controller/Admin/ProductsController.php(407): Cake\ORM\Table->save(Object(App\Model\Entity\Product), Object(ArrayObject))
#15 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(610): App\Controller\Admin\ProductsController->edit('103159')
#16 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(120): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#17 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(94): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\Admin\ProductsController))
#18 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(235): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#19 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#20 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(162): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#21 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#22 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#23 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#24 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(96): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#25 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#26vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#27 vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(98): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#28webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Salines No it does not exist and I am not sure if it should.
I am uploading images to uploads folder not in tmp folder - that is what confuses me the most

Comment: Cake php logs says the same thing. Check this ss https://prnt.sc/ssaazl

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: @ndm cakephp version 3.7.4

Comment: @Salines Ok I found that under tmp folder there are a few files. Check this screenshot - https://prnt.sc/ssd0q9
Mode 600 - Is this could be the problem? Also owner of tmp is root but nginx is www-data. Is this also might be a problem?
The thing is that I haven`t changed these permissions

Comment: With 3.7.4 your app should support logging nested exceptions, and you should not only have the `NotReadableException` logged, but also its inner `ImagickException` exception, which might have more information: **https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/2.5.1/src/Intervention/Image/Imagick/Decoder.php#L28-L32**. Please check your app's error logs (also please always copy errors/exceptions/traces from the logs and post them as text in your question, do not post them as images!).

Comment: @Salines So according to that article should I change permissions or change the funtionality of php code.
This still doesn`t really explain why it happened...

Comment: @ndm Are you saying it is Imagick error rather than server error?

Comment: The original error is an exception that is thrown by Imagick, as you can see in the linked code, what the source/cause of that error is, I have no idea, hence why I asked you to check in your logs for possible details about the Imagick exception.

Comment: @ndm updated question with error logs

Comment: That's only the stacktrace for the `NotReadableException` (please make sure to always include the message too). Aren't there any other errors, there should be a log entry for `ImagickException` too?

Comment: * unless you're using a very old version of `intervention/image`, which doesn't pass on the imagick exception.

Comment: @ndm I don`t really know man. all I can find is these logs above. Also if I do <?php phpinfo ?> I got 502 bad gateway.

Comment: also use always directory separator `DS`  in your config paths, like ` DS . 'upload' . DS . 'images' . DS .$image->id . DS. 'sm_' . $image->image,`

Comment: Maybe because that's invalid syntax... You can of course always go and debug that stuff manually if it doesn't show up in your logs, ie set a breakpoint in `\Intervention\Image\Imagick\Decoder::initFromPath()`, or simply add code in there to dump `$e` and see what the Imagick exception is about.

Comment: @Davis come to https://cakesf.herokuapp.com/  find me salines (javim ti se)

Comment: @ndm Thats the crazy thing - if I do that you mentioned above I got 502 bad gateway.
I am not able to debug this one.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell from here what that might be about... as Salines suggested, maybe join over at Slack to discuss this further.

Comment: not sure if this changes anything but I found this error in logs:
Caused by: [ImagickException] no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504